# How to correctly specify type when passing component as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having a difficult time passing a component as a prop to a simple functional component `RenderRoute`:

```
interface RouteProps {
  component: React.ComponentType;
  isProtected: boolean;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  path?: string;
  exact?: boolean;
};

const RenderRoute: React.FC<RouteProps> = ({ component: Component, isProtected, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => {

  return (
    <Route
        render={(props: ReactRouterDom.RouteComponentProps<{}>) =>
            (!isProtected || (isProtected && isLoggedIn))
                ? <Component {...props} />  // <--- 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
                : <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
        {...rest}
    />
  );
};

const SimpleComponent = () => {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
};

<RenderRoute
    path='/'
    exact={true}
    isProtected={false}
    isLoggedIn={true}
    component={SimpleComponent}
 />
```

As you can see RenderRoute either renders a passed component or renders redirect component.

I'm getting this typescript error:

[image]

Comment: I think `component: FC<RouteComponentProps>;` will work

Comment: @HaiAlaluf it does work; however we have to make it work using only React.ComponentType because it's union of class component & functional component

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the component from `RouteProps` to `ReactNode`

```js
interface RouteProps {
  component: React.ReactNode;
  isProtected: boolean;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  path?: string;
  exact?: boolean;
};
```